# How to extract substring by the comma except for the comma which is marked with quotation marks in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string like

`String str = "1000,\"1123\",aabb,\"aa,bb\",test,\"abcd,\"";`

I want to extract the substring by the delimiter comma ',' except for the comma which is marked with quotation marks. For the above example, I want to get the array is

`1000  1123  abcd  aa,bb  test abcd,`

I tried to use the regular expression, but I failed to find it. Please tell me how should I extract it. Many thanks.

Comment: [`(,)(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/bF7pP9/1)

Comment: @Uchiha it works. Thanks you very much

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helped.

Answer (score -1):

`(,\\"|\",)+` regex can do this what you want

```
str.replaceAll("(,\\\"|\\\",)+", "  ");
```

[**See it in action**](https://ideone.com/r5HrtZ)

---

Regex description:

```
1st Capturing group (,\\"|\",)+
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
1st Alternative: ,\\"
, matches the character , literally
\\ matches the character \ literally
" matches the characters " literally
2nd Alternative: \",
\" matches the character " literally
, matches the character , literally
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

Comment: It might be not worked for the string which end with the ,"    like "abc,\"abc,\",abc". Anyway, thanks for your reply